# Tor 3.5 and the Function "New Identity" = Logins are lost

Tags: anonymity

If I am logged in on a page and will/must use a new identity, the login is lost after the windows are closed and reopened. I cannot make a logout and must log in again. This problem does not exist with vidalia in version 2.x

Comment: What is your actual question...?

Answer (score 4):

This is expected behavior in the TBB; it clears the cookies when you close the window (which is how most sites will store authentication tokens).

Not only is this expected behavior, it's desirable. If an older version of the TBB did not do this, it was a security flaw because cookies could then be used to correlate your old and new identity in the Tor network (effectively rendering creating a new identity useless).

Comment: It's desirable if you want that. But that's not quite what happened. Vidalia's New Identity was written at a time pre-TBB, where Vidalia was simply a GUI for Tor. It was up to the user before to reset their cookies, history etc in their browser separately. But now New Identity has become conflated with the idea of New Identity via the Tor Brower Button in FF which deletes session information (apart from downloads for some reason). Seems to make some sense at first, except the older behavior of creating a new identity with Vidalia while keeping cookies in FF was great if you simply had a bad co